# Android - Custom handling for Navigation Up while using CollapsingToolbar with Navigation Component

Tags: android, kotlin, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-architecture-navigation

Hello I am trying to integrate the collapsing toolbar with navigation component and add custom handling for back/navigation up in some screens.

```
        navHostFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        val navController = navHostFragment.findNavController()

        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            navGraph = navController.graph,
            fallbackOnNavigateUpListener = {
                false
            }
        )

        appBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.appBarLayout)
        val layout = findViewById<CollapsingToolbarLayout>(R.id.collapsing_toolbar_layout)
        val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        layout.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

I used this to initialize my layout, and I noticed that I need to use `layout.setupWithNavController` to allow the collapsing toolbar to read the title from NavGraph and without that my title is not being updated at all!

I had a `onBackPressedDispatcher` listener that was working fine for hardware Back button and Home/NavUp button with `setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)`, however after using CollapsingToolbar and switching to `collapLayout.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController, appBarConfiguration)` I found that my backDispatcher is not working, and therefore my custom back handler is not working either for NavUp button.

I tried to see if functions `onSupportNavigateUp` `onOptionsItemSelected` `onBackPressed` is being triggered, but none of them are anymore if I click on NavUp.

What is the proper way to add custom handler for NavUp while keeping the Collapsing toolbar with the NavComponent?

Is this even possible?

Comment: Try this: add In fragment to handle upNav: `setHasOptionsMenu(true)`  and override `onOptionsItemSelected()` , and check if  `onOptionsItemSelected()`  get triggered

Comment: @Zain no, it is not getting triggered.